# ESRI oracle multi editor schemas

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

**Solution:**

The limitations of the Esri + Oracle (per 12c) were the cause. 12c Oracle will allow for Multi-Tenant DB, allowing us to have multiple SDE GeoDB as we need. This will meeting the need for one owner, and multiple creators in a schema.

**Background**:  Oracle 11g, ArcServer 10.3.1

Our group is trying to organize our geodatabase based on application, much like how SQL Server creates its instances.

All our tables are at the master SDE level, which means that there are impacts on other application during schema deployments or esri upgrades.

We looked at User Geodatabase (user schemas), but they only allow for only editor/creator at the Geodatabase level.

Outside of creating one Oracle instance per application, what are others doing in order to allow for multiple owners and editors?

Comment: Can you please explain further what you mean by "We looked at User Geodatabase (user schemas), but they only allow for only editor/creator at the Geodatabase level." What is the problem with this?

Comment: A user schema geodatabase, only allows one creator, editor. We need the ability to have one owner and multiple creators (connected users.) Esri does not support this.

Comment: Do you mean you need multiple users to be able to create their own data within a single user schema?

Comment: Yes, but not using the 'master' DB. This is a limitation of Oracle (pre 12c) and how Esri has done User geodatabases. We are moving to Oracle 12c, which will give us a multi-tenant DB; allowing each applicaiton we have to have their own db/schema.

Comment: Ah OK I understand now. I was going to suggest giving each app it's own user schema but you are right, the editors couldn't create their own data.

Comment: This question seems to include an answer to it so I think you should cut/paste it into an actual answer.  Self-answering is fine to do and is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The limitations of the Esri + Oracle (per 12c) were the cause. 12c Oracle will allow for Multi-Tenant DB, allowing us to have multiple SDE GeoDB as we need. This will meeting the need for one owner, and multiple creators in a schema.